# Matlab - Grouping some points and sorting according to these groups

Tags: matlab, sorting

I am given a matrix of horizontal edge points. What I want to do is to combine these edge points and find the distance between them if possible.

Let's say, the matrix M below represents the edge points on the xy coordinate plane.

```
M=[15   1
   16   1
   19   1
   21   1
   17   2
   18   2
   94   2
   98   2
   20   3
   95   3
   97   3
   96   4
   16   20
   18   20
   21   20
   17   21
   19   22
   20   23];
```

What I want to do is to combine closer points in a piecewise fashion and get the matrix below:

```
M=[15   1
   16   1
   17   2
   18   2
   19   1
   20   3
   21   1
   16   20
   17   21
   18   20
   19   22
   20   23
   21   20
   94   2
   95   3
   96   4
   97   3
   98   2];
```

which means the points that are close to each other are shown together. Sorting using M=sortrows(M,1) or M=sortrows(M,2) doesn't group the points together. What should I be using?

Comment: the graph that shows your points and the drawing you want to have as output do not fit together. it doesn't make sense. also it is not clear why sorting coordinates is no solution for creating clusters. and what is it you want to know? provide some code, not just sketches and coordinates. this is not a coding service.

Comment: @Piglet You are right, I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @Piglet I never intended for the whole code, I just couldn't know how to model such a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clustering problem, not a sorting problem.  Try using `kmeans` (which performs *k*-means clustering, a well known method to find groups of data that are close together).

If you have the MATLAB Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox, use the built-in [kmeans](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) function (run `ver` to see your installed toolboxes). You must specify the number of clusters.  For a simple dataset like the one you have posted, this is easy to do by looking at a scatter plot (`scatter(M(:,1), M(:,2))`).

Run *k*-means clustering, which outputs a vector containing the cluster that each point belongs to:

```
clusters = kmeans(M, 3)
```

Add this as the third column of `M` sort by that column. The 3rd column now denotes which cluster each point is in (e.g., all points with `1` in the third column are a group).

```
M(:,3) = clusters
groupedData = sortrows(M, 3)

16    20     1
18    20     1
21    20     1
17    21     1
19    22     1
20    23     1
94     2     2
98     2     2
95     3     2
97     3     2
96     4     2
15     1     3
16     1     3
19     1     3
21     1     3
17     2     3
18     2     3
20     3     3
```

You could then select the points in a single group using logical indexing:

`M(M(:,3) == 1, :)`

```
16    20     1
18    20     1
21    20     1
17    21     1
19    22     1
20    23     1
```

If you do not have the MATLAB Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox package, this file from the FileExchange could be a good replacement: [Kmeans Clustering by Mo Chen](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24616-kmeans-clustering)